# How do you set each letter in an array as a coordinate?

Tags: c

The code opens a file containing a 2D array of letters. I have already made the code to open the file:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define MAXC 1024

int main (void){

    FILE* fp = NULL; 
    size_t nlines = 0;
    char a[MAXC] = "";

    printf("Enter a filename: ");
    fscanf (stdin, " %1023[^\n]", a);
        
    
    if ((fp = fopen (a, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror ("could not open file");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("file opened: %s\n\n", a);

    while (fgets (a, MAXC, fp) != NULL)
      
        printf ("line[%zu]: %s", nlines++ + 1, a);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

and the output looks something like this:

```
Enter a filename: test.txt
file opened: test.txt

line[1]: SSSS
line[2]: BBSS
line[3]: RSSB
line[4]: SSSS
```

From here, the user inputs coordinates (0 0 for top left, 0 1, 0 2 etc.). Depending on what letter is at that coordinate the user either wins or loses the game... This is the part I am stuck on. How can I assign each letter an i/j value where i is the row and j is column? Or is there something totally different I should be doing?

Comment: Given a coordinate as (i,j), i is the current line number read (ie. linesRead, starting from 0) and j is the index into the string representing the line (starting from zero). This can be used directly is checking while reading the file or as constructing arrays (the string read can itself be treated as an array)..

Comment: That is, letters are not “assigned” coordinates any more than a grid on a piece of graph paper is “assigned” a coordinate.

Comment: So if I have an array of chars, how can I make the code know that, for example '0 0' is an 'S'?

Comment: But an array of chars is just one line of the file.  You need to store all the lines in arrays, so you need an array of lines from the file.

Comment: `nlines++ + 1` really? Why not just `++nlines`?

Comment: There is a reason why professional coding style guides request a separate statement for increment and decrement operations. It makes the source so much easier to grasp. And it is more logical that you increment `nlines` right after a successful `fgets()` and before any further work.